# Break out parts of a LINQ2SQL Expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I have this piece of LINQ code

```
private static void Original()
{
    using (var context = new AdventureWorksContext())
    {
        var result =
            from product in context.Products
            from workorder in product.WorkOrders
            select new
            {
                productName = product.Name,
                order = workorder,
            };

        var result2 =
            from item in result
            where item.order.WorkOrderRoutings.Count() == 1
            select item.productName;

        foreach (var item in result2.Take(10))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to break out the `item.order.WorkOrderRoutings.Count()` part and replace with something else, like `item.order.OrderQty` based on some input parameter.

My first attempt:

```
private static Func<WorkOrder, int> GetRoutingCountFunc()
{
    return workOrder => workOrder.WorkOrderRoutings.Count();
}

private static void RefactoredFunc()
{
    using (var context = new AdventureWorksContext())
    {
        var result =
            from product in context.Products
            from workorder in product.WorkOrders
            select new
            {
                productName = product.Name,
                order = workorder,
            };

        var result2 =
            from item in result
            where GetRoutingCountFunc()(item.order) == 1
            select item.productName;

        foreach (var item in result2.Take(10))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

of course fails a runtime with an exception

> Method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' has no supported translation to SQL.

So I figured out I need to put in some kind of `Expression`. The most reasonable I can figure out is

```
private static Expression<Func<WorkOrder, int>> GetRoutingCountExpression()
{
    return workOrder => workOrder.WorkOrderRoutings.Count();
}

private static void RefactoredExpression()
{
    using (var context = new AdventureWorksContext())
    {
        var result =
            from product in context.Products
            from workorder in product.WorkOrders
            select new
            {
                productName = product.Name,
                order = workorder,
            };

        var result2 =
            from item in result
            where GetRoutingCountExpression()(item.order) == 0
            select item.productName;

        foreach (var item in result2.Take(10))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But that gives a compile time error: "Method name expected" on the line `where GetRoutingCountExpression()(item.order) == 0`.

If it wasn't for the anonymous type I could have created a method returning `Expression<Func<"anonType", bool>>` and use that as the where argument.

How do I break out parts of the LINQ-expression?

Comment: http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx you can try this direction

Comment: +1 for Adrian Iftodes answer. I had the exact same problem and I ended up using the predicatebuilder which solved my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to create methods that transform `IQueryable<T>` instances. For instance a method like this:

```
private static IQueryable<WorkOrder> FilterByRoutingCount(
    IQueryable<WorkOrder> orders, int count)
{
    return
        from workOrder in orders, 
        where workOrder.WorkOrderRoutings.Count() == count)
        select workOrder;
}
```

You can use this method like this:

```
var workorders =
    from product in context.Products
    from workorder in product.WorkOrders
    select workorder;

var result2 =
    from workorder in FilterByRoutingCount(workorders, 1)
    select workorder.Product.productName;
```

Comment: The problem is that `result` is an anonymous type. I don't get how to project out the orders. I tried `from workorder in GetRoutingCount(product.WorkOrders, 1)` in the first select, but that gives me the compile time error `cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.EntitySet<ConsoleApplication1.WorkOrder>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<ConsoleApplication1.WorkOrder>'`.

Comment: @Albin: You can almost always solve these problems by rewriting your LINQ queries. Try trick here of course is to ditch the anonymous type. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do like:

```
private static int GetRoutingCount(WorkOrder w)
{
    return w.WorkOrderRoutings.Count();
}
```

If we assume that `item.order` is of type `WorkOrder`, then you could use it like:

```
var result2 =
    from item in result
    where GetRoutingCount(item.order) == 0
    select item.productName;
```

---

**Edit**

This should do the job:

```
Expression<Func<Tuple<string, Order>, bool>> routingCountZero = x => 
    x.Item2.Roundings.Count == 0;
```

You'll have to use lambda expressions:

```
var result2 = result.Where(routingCountZero).Select(x => x.Item1);
```

Comment: You could (it both compiles and executes), but this will not translate into a single SQL command, this will enumerate `result` first and then call `GetRoutingCount` repeatedly for each item in `result` causing too many calls to the SQL server.